# Is it a good practice to keep autocomplete on in login form?

Tags: design-patterns, login, autocomplete

We recently revamped the UI of our Login form and initially kept the autocomplete on in the Email/ID field. We then created a blog inside our website and users loved it. They also loved the fact that they were able to save passwords in the browser.

But later we realized that it might not be safe to do so. So, we have disabled the autocomplete.

I wanted to know is it safe to do so. Disabling autocomplete might have brought down the user experience aspect.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly it probably depends on how secure you want to be - it will definitely be a tradeoff. I have noticed that banks and other money related services usually don't have it enabled.

I would say that if you handle extremely sensitive data such as money or insurances you want to keep it disabled. If you are operating something less sensitive like a social media site, UX might matter to you more than having the best security measures.

Also keep in mind passwords are not the only way to secure accounts. You could also for example implement optional 2-factor authentication for users who want high account security.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, traditional login patterns such as password logins call for trade-offs between UX and security. Unless you are willing to try alternate login patterns the effectiveness of your UX will decrease when you increase you raise your security standards.